# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array -> When fitting keras model (KerasClassifier) with X (list of strings) // Fitting only keras modell works

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

hopefully you can help me.

The above error mentioned in the title occurs, when trying to fit a self created keras model with training data X (list of strings) in combination with the KerasClassifier.
The error does NOT occur when fitting the self created keras model without the KerasClassifier.

I thought already about the type(X) I am passing, which could be the problem, but the TextVectorization layer should tokenize the data on itself. The TextVectorization layer is also adapted to the training data.

Since I am using a TextVectorization layer, I do NOT want to pass before transformed data, related to the Tokenizer class, fit_on_texts method, texts_to_sequences method and tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences method.
Keras mentions, "Deprecated: tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer does not operate on tensors and is not recommended for new code.".

Therefore I want to do all these steps related to the Tokenizer class with the TextVectorization class.

- Important: Why, because I want the "output_sequence_length" parameter of the TextVectorization class to be a Hyperparameter.

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

```
def Build_Model(X_train, nodes=10, nLayers=1, epochs=10, batch_size=32, dropout=0.5,       act_h='relu', act_o='sigmoid', optimizer='adam', verbose=2, emb_matrix=None, vocab=None,   sequence_length=200):

   vectorize_layer = TextVec_Layer(vocab, sequence_length)
   embedding_layer = Emb_Layer(emb_matrix, sequence_length)
   model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
   vectorize_layer.adapt(X_train)
   model.add(vectorize_layer)
   model.add(embedding_layer)
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(nodes, activation=act_h))
   model.add(Dropout(dropout))

   model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation=act_o))                 
   model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,                                 
               loss= 'binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

   return model


emb_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=Build_Model, X_train=X_train, nodes=10, nLayers=1, epochs=10,    batch_size=100, dropout=0.5, act_h='relu', act_o='sigmoid', optimizer='adam', emb_matrix=emb_matrix, vocab=vocab, sequence_length=100,verbose=2, random_state=42)

model = emb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)
...\Temp/ipykernel_18552/393945425.py in <module>
----> 1 emb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)#, , validation_data=(X_test_t, y_test)

...\wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1492             sample_weight = 1 if sample_weight is None else sample_weight
   1493             sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight(class_weight=self.class_weight, y=y)
-> 1494         super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1495         return self
   1496 

...\wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    760         kwargs["initial_epoch"] = kwargs.get("initial_epoch", 0)
    761 
--> 762         self._fit(
    763             X=X,
    764             y=y,

...\wrappers.py in _fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    916         # Data checks
    917         if not ((self.warm_start or warm_start) and self.initialized_):
--> 918             X, y = self._initialize(X, y)
    919         else:
    920             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I lately found the aspect, which is causing the above problem, I want state it.
The actual problem was trying to fit 1-dimensional data to the KerasClassifier, which does not accept that.